# When i am trying to migrate my code from 32 to 64 bit , Gsoap gives me warnings related to -Wsign-conversion, how to resolve this warnings?

Tags: c, soapui, gsoap

Gsoap gives me warnings related to -Wsign-conversion, since gsoap source files are auto generated i am unable to resolve these warnings. Can someone please me with this. Thanks in advance.

**64bit Warnings example**

warning: conversion to long unsigned int from int may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
`char *a = (char*)soap_malloc((soap), (n = (n < 0 ? 1 : n)) * sizeof(char));`

**32bit warnings example**
warning: conversion to unsigned int from int may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
`char *a = (char*)soap_malloc((soap), (n = (n < 0 ? 1 : n)) * sizeof(char));`

I went through their document but not much help in that regarding above warnings.

Comment: What is the type of `n`?

Comment: @NathanOliver It is evident that n has the type int.:)

Comment: You got warning in both 32/64bit mode? if so, it is not a migration issue.

Comment: `static_cast<std::size_t>(n = (n < 0 ? 1 : n))`?

Comment: @dex_nav Either declare n as having an unsigned integer type as for example size_t or use an explicit casting of the expression with n to the type size_t.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Its an auto generated file. i am not able to change anything in the source file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignore the warning. It's generated code, you cannot change it.

However, you can easily see that it is a false positive: The test `n = (n < 0 ? 1 : n)` specifically guarantees that the number is positive before the conversion; all negative numbers become `1`.

There is no danger here in converting a signed 32 or 64 bit `int` to its unsigned equivalent when the signed value is guaranteed to be positive.